# Python GUI Menu Issue

Tags: python, user-interface, menu, tkinter

I am trying to create a code that establishes a menu on my gui using python. The issue is, it keeps calling the function the null function when I create the New option under file. It is only supposed to go off when I click on new, but it goes off when I run the program. I used the print function in null to let me know when it's being called

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.setup()

    def null(self):
        print('o')


    def setup(self):


        board = tk.Canvas(self.master, width = 800, height = 800)
        board.pack()

        #Creates the Walls/Floor
        board.create_line(0, 790,800, 790, width = 20) #Creates Bottom Line
        board.create_line(10, 800,10, 100, width = 35) #Creates Left Wall
        board.create_line(790, 800, 790, 100, width = 35) #Creates Right Wall

        space = 20
        for x in range(6): #Creates pillars
            space += 108.5
            board.create_line(space, 800, space, 150, width = 20)

            board.pack() 

    def newgame(self):        
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.master)
        self.filemenu = tk.Menu(self.master, tearoff = 0)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="New", command = self.null())
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.filemenu)
        self.filemenu.add_separator()
        self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.null` is being invoked (going off) because you are telling it to do so by placing `()` after it.  Remember that Python uses `(...)` after a function name to invoke that function.

To fix the problem, simply remove the parenthesis:

```
self.filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.null)
```

Now, `command` is set to a *reference* of `self.null`.